# Is it possible to show the latest Push Notification in a Label in the StoryBoard?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilabel, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I like to show the latest Push Notification in a label in my main StoryBoard I use this code to display the alert message in my AppDelegate.m:

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    NSDictionary *test =(NSDictionary *)[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
    NSString *alertString =(NSString *) [test objectForKey:@"alert"];
    NSLog(@"String recieved: %@",alertString);


    UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];

    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        UIAlertView *alertmessage=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Geier"
                                                            message:alertString                                                   delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];


        [alertmessage show];

        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(1002);


    }

}
```

i tried this in my ViewController.m file `latestpush.text = @"%@",alertString;` but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the text available to the view controller.

You could do this by sending a custom NSNotification with the alert message, from inside `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
        postNotificationName:@"PushAlertNotification" 
        object:self
        userInfo:@{@"alertString":alertString}];
```

In your view controller's viewDidLoad method, register as an observer:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector(updateStoryboard:)
                                        name:@"PushAlertNotification"
                                        object:nil];
```

and create the `updateStoryboard:` method in the view controller:

```
- (void) updateStoryboard:(NSNotification *) notification {
    self.latestpush.text = notification.userInfo[@"alertString"];
}
```

---

An alternative solution is to create a property in your AppDelegate that takes in the ViewController as an observer.

AppDelegate.h (change ViewController to the actual type of your VC).

`@property (nonatomic, weak) ViewController *observer;`

Inside the ViewController create a method that accepts the NSString and have that method update your Storyboard.

ViewController.m

```
-(void)updateStoryboard(NSString *alertString) {
   self.latestpush.text = alertString;
}
```

Also, in your ViewContoller's viewDidLoad method, register yourself with the appDelegate:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    delegate.observer = self;
}
```

Call updateStoryboard inside your `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method:

`[self.observer updateStoryboard:alertString];`

Comment: @j_Shapiro Both methods wont work for me:( but I made it exactly how you said it.

Comment: Give me some more info to go on... how are they not working?  Is alertString nil before you create the notification? What errors are you seeing?

Comment: There is no error the Push comes in but the label is not filled out with the Push message.

Comment: Before you post the message... is it nil?

Comment: If you mean the Label in the viewDidUnload yes it is set to nil: latestpush = nil;

Comment: There are two likely problems: alertString is nil or latestpush is not properly configured as an outlet.  Try hardcoding a string in the updateStoryboard method: `self.latestpush.text = @"TESTING!"`  If that doesn't show up, there is a problem with the outlet.  If it does, check to see if alertString is nil or empty.